# Add Stops Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Trying to add stops to my trading view backtest.
Every time I add a stop loss it either gets ignored or I get stopped out and immediately reenter the position. I wanted to add a percentage stop and the option to either add a stop that moves with the moving average or a fixed stop value.

```
// @version = 5
strategy("Pairs Trading Moving Average", shorttitle = "Pairs Trading MA", overlay = true, process_orders_on_close = true, backtest_fill_limits_assumption = 0)

//          Inputs

long_short = input.string(title = "Long/Short?", options = ["Long", "Short", "Both"], defval = "Both" )
LEVERAGE = input.float(title="Leverage", defval=1)

maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "VWAP", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA", "HMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "ZLEMA", "THMA", "EHMA"], group="MA Settings")
len = input(30, title="Length")
multiplier = input.float(title = "Stdev Multiplier", defval = 2)
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")
off_s = input(title="Offset Plot", defval=1)

startDate = input.int(title="Start Date",
     defval=1)
startMonth = input.int(title="Start Month",
     defval=1)
startYear = input.int(title="Start Year",
     defval=2018)
endDate = input.int(title="End Date",
     defval=1)
endMonth = input.int(title="End Month",
     defval=1)
endYear = input.int(title="End Year",
     defval=2025)

//          Moving Averages

vwap(src, len) => math.sum((src * volume), len) / math.sum(volume, len)
dema(src, len) => 2 * ta.ema(src, len) - ta.ema(ta.ema(src, len), len)
tema(src, len) => 3 * (ta.ema(src, len) - ta.ema(ta.ema(src, len), len)) + ta.ema(ta.ema(ta.ema(src, len), len), len)
zlema(src, len) =>
    lag = math.round((len - 1) / 2)
    ema_data = src + (src - src[lag])
    zl= ta.ema(ema_data, len)
ehma(src, len) =>  ta.ema(2 * ta.ema(src, len / 2) - ta.ema(src, len), math.round(math.sqrt(len)))
thma(src, len) =>  ta.wma(ta.wma(src,len / 3) * 3 - ta.wma(src, len / 2) - ta.wma(src, len), len)

ma(src, len, type) =>
    switch type
        "EHMA" => ehma(src, len)
        "THMA" => thma(src, len)
        "ZLEMA" => zlema(src, len)
        "TEMA" => tema(src, len)
        "DEMA" => dema(src, len)
        "SMA" => ta.sma(src, len)
        "VWAP" => vwap(src, len)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(src, len)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(src, len)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(src, len)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(src, len)
        "HMA" => ta.hma(src, len)

//          Variables

out = ma(src, len, maTypeInput)
above = out + (ta.stdev(src, len) * multiplier)
below = out - (ta.stdev(src, len) * multiplier)

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))

//          Plots

plot(out, offset=off_s)
plot(above, color = color.red, offset=off_s)
plot(below, color = color.green, offset=off_s)

//          Position Sizing

long_qty = math.floor(strategy.equity * LEVERAGE / below)
short_qty = math.floor(strategy.equity * LEVERAGE / above)

//          Order Execution

if inDateRange
    if long_short == "Long"
        strategy.cancel_all()
        strategy.entry("Bullish IB", strategy.long, qty=long_qty, limit=below)
        strategy.exit("Bullish Exit","Bullish IB", limit=out)
    if long_short == "Short"
        strategy.cancel_all()
        strategy.entry("Bearish IB", strategy.short, qty=short_qty, limit=above)
        strategy.exit("Bearish Exit","Bearish IB", limit=out)
    if long_short == "Both"
        strategy.cancel_all()
        strategy.entry("Bearish IB", strategy.short, qty=short_qty, limit=above)
        strategy.exit("Bearish Exit","Bearish IB", limit=out)
        strategy.entry("Bullish IB", strategy.long, qty=long_qty, limit=below)
        strategy.exit("Bullish Exit","Bullish IB", limit=out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
if strategy.position_size >  0
   strategy.exit("Long", limit = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.02, stop = 
   strategy.position_avg_price * 0.99, comment = 'Long Exit')
```

Comment: Try adding a little bit of explanation rather than saying here you go, even if it's just as simple as 'this is an x that will do y'